# Use DBMS_SCHEDULER repeat_interval to run a task once in two days

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

I am trying to create a task  (delete some cache data) that will run once in two days. This will run on `Oracle 11g`. So far I came up with the following anonymous block:

```
 begin 
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
     job_name             => 'clear_cache',
     job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
     job_action           => 'begin delete from MY_CACHE;commit; end;',
     start_date           =>  to_date('19/09/2016','dd/mm/rrrr')+ 19/24,
     repeat_interval      => 'to_date(''19/09/2016'',''dd/mm/rrrr'')+ 2 + 19/24',
     enabled              => TRUE); 
  end;
```

However, I am not sure about repeat_interval value..

Assuming that I will run this block today (`15/09/2016`), I want `clear_cache`  to be executed on:

```
19/09/2016 at 7 p.m 
21/09/2016 at 7 p.m.
23/09/2016 at 7 p.m. 
etc
```

I know that if i use

```
 start_date           =>  sysdate,
 repeat_interval      => 'trunc(sysdate) + 7 + 7/24'
```

Then it will start execution `today`, will repeat every `7` days at `7 p.m.`, what I want,though, is to begin next Monday and repeat every 2nd day and I am not sure how to achieve that...

So, I would like to know what exactly to put into `repeat_interval` ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worth using the [built-in calendaring syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72262) rather than trying to roll your own. By stating that you want the job to run daily with an interval of 2 it will run every 2 days.

The syntax is `FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2`, if you set the start date to 7pm then it'll start at that time in your current timezone.

The `start_date` parameter is a date, so you can use an actual date or timestamp here.

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
     job_name             => 'clear_cache',
     job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
     job_action           => 'begin delete from MY_CACHE; commit; end;',
     start_date           => timestamp '2016-09-19 19:00:00',
     repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2',
     enabled              => TRUE);
```